Complete list of Environment Canada weather stations in Ontario
Where does Environment Canada have weather stations in Ontario? Specifically, weather stations that are used to create Environment Canada weather forecasts.
There is a map on this page: https://weather.gc.ca/forecast/canada/index_e.html?id=ON

But I don't think the map includes all weather stations. I say that because I believe there is a weather station in Bancroft, Ontario. But Bancroft isn't included in the map.

https://weather.gc.ca/en/location/index.html?coords=44.817,-77.186
The first link (with the map) has a list of 1,943 locations. But I suspect the weather forecasts are interpolated (estimated) for those locations. I don't think there are weather stations in all of those locations, especially the small towns.
Where can I find a complete list or map of all Environment Canada weather stations in Ontario?
I've asked Environment Canada, but haven't gotten a response yet.

Ontario has had 1643 operational weather stations between 1840 and 2024. You may need to look at the Historical Data site for Environment Canada.
The website for the Ontario.
